# Unable to load class: org.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to connect a fairly standard dropwizard app to a mysql database. It seems like a lot of people have been having this problem but I cannot figure out what is wrong with my project. It seems like adding in mysql-connector should have worked for me but when I run the following I still get  Unable to load class: org.mysql.jdbc.Driver.

`java -jar target/bitly-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server src/config.yml`

Does anyone see what might be incorrect. I also found a lot of responses of adding this to my classpath in IntelliJ and I did that by going to File > Project Structure > Libraries and then adding in the mysql maven dependency but still won't work.

Is there something I am missing?

Full link to repo here. 
https://github.com/Jazilch/bit.ly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## short

If You are using maven, just try:
`mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main"`

## long

I suspect that the bitly-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar does not contain all dependencies ("fat jar", like build by spring-boot).
So the problem is, that `java -jar target/bitly-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server src/config.yml` does not include 3rd-party-dependencies in the classpath.
`mvn exec:java ...` builds a classpath with all dependencies defined in the pom.
With the JVM You add 3rd-Party-Jars to the classpath with the `-cp` option.

Comment: I tried to run this with the following command  `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.zilch.bitly" ` But when I ran this I got the following 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zilch.bitly

Comment: You have to replace com.zilch.bitly with the fully qualified class name of your main class.

Comment: This seemed to work for me. It didn't seem to start my dropwizard server though

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating the *jar* using IntelliJ, make sure you included all available elements from your Maven's dependency. To do so, go to:

> File > Project Structure > Artifacts

Now select (or add a new jar artifact) all available elements found on the right pane, by double clicking on each one of them all select or select them all, right click in any of the highlighted elements and choose `Put into output root`. The screen should look something like the one below.

[image]

Now, just rebuild your artifacts and this should do the trick.

Comment: I added the dependency and tried to run the following command but still getting the same error. 
`mvn package`
`java -jar target/bitly-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server src/config.yml`

Should I be running a different command now?

Comment: Actually, since you are using IntelliJ, you can let the IDE build it for you. Go to `Build > Build Artifacts...` then on the small window, choose all `All Artifacts > Rebuild`.